# Confirm jQuery sortable receive event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two separate ul lists:
list-A and list-B

both of them are sortable thanks to the jQuery UI plugin.

Users of the project I'm working on wants to confirm the action when items are moved from one list to the other, but *not* when moving within the same list. When an action is triggered, the page will launch an Ajax request to the server to update the positions of the list(s).

What's troubling me is the order of the events. My experience so far is that the update event is triggered before the receive event so before the confirm dialog is shown, a request has already been initiated.

Unfortunately I forget which of the lists that trigger the request but in my case it really does not matter: if an item is dragged onto another list, nothing should be sent to the server until the user has confirmed the action.

I've used jQuery quite a bit but I think I could use some help on this one.

**Javascript:**

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).addClass("sortable-drag-clone");
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).removeClass("sortable-drag-clone");
    },
    update: function (event, ui) {

        if ($(ui.sender).length == 0) {
            alert("item was moved within the same list.");
            //Make request
        } else {
            //do nothing.
        }
    },
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        if (confirm("show move or copy dialog, from {0} to {1}")) {
            //do request
        } else {
            $(ui.sender).sortable("cancel");
            //no request
        }
    },
    tolerance: "pointer",
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    placeholder: "sortable-draggable-placeholder",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 666
}).disableSelection();
```

**Markup:**

```
<div id="list-A">
    <ul class="sortable">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="list-B">
    <ul class="sortable">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Update:

**Scenario I)**
user drags A1 to A3 - result is no confirm dialog so a request is sent to the server so that the new sort order is persisted.

**Scenario II)**
user drags A1 to B3 (or B3 to A1) - result is a confirm dialog and then, only if the dialog is accepted, a request is sent to the server. This is where I've settled with two requests as I described in one of my comments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `update` method then, just remove it! [Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/xTkGB/).

Comment: Almost there but not quite. It does not pickup sortable events within the same list. However, I did get it to work by setting a data-attribute ("doConfirm", true) and resetting it in the stop event handler. I'll see if I can find the code. It is not perfect: it causes two requests to be sent to the server (one for list-A and one for list-B). Ideally I was hoping to aggregate the items myself and fire off a single request.

Comment: @Adam Asham: I'm lost! you want to send to the server when the user confirm the move from one list to another? can you list the scenarios when the server call should be requested.

Comment: Sorry, I must have done a poor job at explaining. I've updated the question with two scenarios.